# Cannot find out arm_control_msgs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS groovy on Ubuntu precise. Recently I am trying to convert a code which works on Diamondback to Groovy. But the problem is that some files used to be available in Diamondback now does not exist in Groovy. For example, when I look at file "`regression_test_pose_goal_floorobj.cpp`"  located at "`/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/arm_navigation/move_arm/test/regression_test_pose_goal_floorobj.cpp` ", it has "`#include <arm_control_msgs/TrajectoryStart.h>`" but I cannot find TrajectoryStart.h, even worse, I cannot find out any folder or file named arm_control_msgs in the root directory of groovy. When I search for the [dos of packages](http://docs.ros.org/) of Diamondback and Electric, I cannot find out anything similar to arm_control_msgs. So :

1. anyone can help me find out where "arm_control_msgs" is?
2. Or tell me what kind of changes have been made to this file(or package?) in Groovy so that I cannot include the new version of header file in my program or make some changes to my program.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189804/cannot-find-out-arm_control_msgs/) by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-12**:
Did you create this cpp file in this path?

**Comment by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on 2014-08-12**:
Do you mean the "regression_test_pose_goal_floorobj.cpp"? No, I don't create it; it comes with the groovy distro. @BennyRe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm not mistaken this has now been replaced by [moveit](http://moveit.ros.org/). It should be easy enough to migrate to use moveit, there are extensive tutorials on their website.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on 2014-08-12**:
Does it mean that I have to re-write a new code using Moveit! or I can use the Moveit! substitute header files(messages)?

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2014-08-13**:
You'll have at least to integrate your robot with moveit (if it's not done already by someone else). Then it shouldn't too much trouble to adapt your code (just changing the message type might work, not exactly sure of what you're doing).